# Remove write protection in Windows

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, write-protect

Why do I always get "cannot write please remove the write protection" when I copy files on C: ? I selected that my account have full control, but i still get this error. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have full control, if a folder is "read-only" it will prevent you from copying files into it.  Full control allows you to change the properties to read/write, and then copy the files.

If you could copy files into read-only folders, this would have some unhelpful consequences.

However, it would be odd if the root of C is read-only.  What folder are you trying to copy into?

Comment: Im trying to copy in C:\ not in any folder

Comment: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistasecurity/thread/78cc11ec-c543-418d-9183-131318e9db8a

Comment: @vBx: What happens if you try to copy into say C:\NewFolder\ ?